# Create Excel file in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, image, excel, csv

I want to create a Excel supported file which contains strings and images programmatically. I tried to create a .csv file, but I am not able to .csv file with both string and image.

Answer (score -1):

There are many possibilities. The easiest way is to create CSV-Files but you have to take care which seperators excel uses. For checking that you should create a spreadsheet in excel and save it as csv and take a look into that file using any text-editor.

Another approach is to use [SpreadsheetML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) and here a [link to the msdn XML Spreadsheet Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx)

Otherwise just create a simple xlsx-file with excel, unzip that file and take a look into that the unziped files.